# How to reverse the direction of Y-Axis of MatLab figure generated by `imagesc()` function

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am trying to display data in a matrix using `imagesc()` function but it is showing row index in decreasing order (Assuming origin at left-bottom). Any idea what mistake i could be making or how to correct this?

The matrix only has zeros and ones in it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `Ydir` property of the `current axes` to `normal`

By default, `imagesc` uses `reverse` for `YDir`

```
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
```

See [Documentation](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) for Axes properties

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

> **Note:** This completely flips the inside data as well (it supposed to). As you are dealing with matrices, I hope this is what you want.
>
> If you don't want to affect inside data, you need to change order of `YTickLabels` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There's another option which requires slightly less code:

```
axis ij
```

> Reverse the coordinate system so that the y values increase from top to bottom.

As in this case (as it is already reversed), you could use

```
axis xy
```

> To get back to normal, so that y values increases from bottom to top.

As mentioned in the docs of [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html#bul_e1h-1).

Comment: Edited for this specific case. Hope you don't mind :)